# Notebook boots into EFI Shell, instead of booting straight to Windows

Tags: boot, bios, windows-11, uefi, efi-system-partition

Recently I bought a MSI laptop, without Operating System.

So I Installled Windows 11 from USB Stick, and everything gone pretty much well. Also, before installing to my SSD I noticed, that there were already 3 partitions created. One marked as EFI, one of size around 400-500gb, representing my SSD and also another one which I cannot remmember now.

The problem is that my PC doesn't boot straight to Windows, but instead goes firstly to EFI Shell and I must write exit and then the PC boots into Windows successfully.

In MSI Click Bios:

- I made sure that in booting order is the Boot Manager in first place.
- I have Secure Boot enabled.
- Changing the UEFI type is greyed out.

Is there any way to force the PC to boot straight to Windows, or I did something wrong/forgot to do something?

Comment: Did you delete those partitions before you installed Windows?

Comment: I did not touch the EFI and the third partition. I formatted the partition representing my SSD, deleted it and created a new partition from it.

Comment: Make sure you are allowing Windows to make the 3 partitions (as I noted in my answer)

Comment: So, when the installer prompts me to install the windows to selected partitions. And I will see the same list of partitions, I am supposed to delete all of them an create a new one for the system? (previously I left the 2 other partitions there). Sorry if I did not understood correctly.

Comment: Yes, delete all of them so Windows can create all 3.

Comment: Okay thanks for clarification. I will try and post an update later this evening.

Comment: @rufo123 - Your system already had an operating system, if it had an EFI partition, storage devices on systems without an operating system have no partitions by default. So by not deleting all partitions you installed Windows which likely created it's own EFI partition but you are not actually attempting to boot from it.

Comment: I deleted the other partitions, installed windows and now it boots straight to Windows. Thank's!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure you get a Windows 11 ISO to make a USB key from Microsoft. At some point you will likely have to pay for this license.

Then, I suggest you redo the installation, format the entire disk and allow Windows to make the basic 3 partitions.

Make sure EUFI, Secure Boot are both enabled at the time of installation.

Done properly (allow Windows to make the partitions) always works.